# Fortnightly challenge - what is the actual challenge?

Tags: discussion

I feel pretty stupid asking this but what is the challenge? Is it just to submit a question?

I notice that, when the deadline has passed, the questions are shown in numerical order but I can't for the life of me see what criterion is used for ordering them.

Can someone enlighten me please.

Comment: It's a challenge to the community as a whole to boost activity in one area, not to any individual...

Comment: So the objective is to accumulate more questions and answers on worldbuilding site to drive traffic, topic is based on rng for fairness, I don't really care for these I just want to see the limits of my imagination that's all. and to learn from everyone here.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is simply to post a post in that tag. That can be a question or an answer to a question in the tag. Its aim is to increase activity in that tag, which has been fairly successful so far.

Most of the challenge posts are now automatically generated using [this generator](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge). Being the author of said generator, I can tell you that the numbering is simply a product of how the posts are returned from the API. I don't think there's an order to that, though it may be by date.

Comment: Where does the generator send its output? Can I play around by entering stuff in the boxes and looking at the results on my screen or will it produce actual posts on the site?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK The output gets put in an output box at the bottom, no posts get made.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I plan to throw the source onto GitHub tomorrow; if you've got bugs or feature requests for me, use the issue tracker there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a challenge since the goal is too increase the activity on the website by promoting certain topics. Wolrdbuilding SE is over 300 days old and half of the [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) question were asked during the 14 days of the "challenge". Since, it doubled the number of questions for that tag, I would call it a success.

The questions are usually show in order with the oldest first or the newest first (it depend on the person writing the message).

We also used to write every single answer as well because the goal is to give good quality content not just to produce unanswered questions. We stopped doing it because we have an average of 5 answers by question and it takes a lot of time to enter them all.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to omit the numbering? I believe it gives the impression that the questions are arranged  in order of merit, with the 'winner' being number 1.